# More effective/elegant way of copying used ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy certain columns from a sheet to another (around 15).

My current method is less than ideal (I think).

```
Sheets(2).Range("A:A").Value = Sheets(1).Range("C:C").Value
Sheets(2).Range("C:C").Value = Sheets(1).Range("G:G").Value
Sheets(2).Range("D:D").Value = Sheets(1).Range("T:T").Value
```

It looks repetitive and more importantly it copies the entire column, which slows down the process by loading the empty rows until the end of the sheet as well.

I'm trying to figure out the best possible way to copy the columns *just* up to the last used column.

This is my current idea, but the empty cells in the second sheet are filled with the *not available* error value, which defeats the purpose.

```
lastRow = Sheets(1).Range("C" & Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets(2).Range("A:A").Value = Sheets(1).Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Value
```

Any function that I'm probably not aware of? Thank you!

(And yes, this must be done in VBA. Ask my boss .)

Comment: Try `Sheets(2).Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value = Sheets(1).Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Value`. When copying ranges like this, both ranges must be same size. You were doing A:A = C1:Clastrow, different quantity of cells because A:A is more than 1 million cells and C1:Clastrow could be 100, 2836, 3, or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your source range is smaller, you have to adjust the size of your target range.

```vb
Sub copyData()

Dim arrColumns(1, 2) As String
'mapping source column : target column
arrColumns(0, 0) = "C": arrColumns(1, 0) = "A"
arrColumns(0, 1) = "G": arrColumns(1, 1) = "C"
arrColumns(0, 2) = "I": arrColumns(1, 2) = "D"

With ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet: Set wsSource = .Worksheets(1)
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet: Set wsTarget = .Worksheets(2)
End With


Dim lastRow As Long
With wsSource
    lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

'now we can do the copying
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(arrColumns, 2)
    wsTarget.Columns(arrColumns(1, i)).Resize(lastRow).Value = wsSource.Columns(arrColumns(0, i)).Resize(lastRow).Value
Next

End Sub
```

Furthermore I like to have mapping arrays at the beginning of such a sub.
In case your boss wants another column to be copied - or copy one to another target column this is much easier to handle.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is such an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

To make it simple, maybe this can work for you:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim SourceArray As Variant
Dim DestinyArray As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long

'all ranges must be same size to work so all of them will use same lastRow

SourceArray = Array("A1:A", "C1:C", "D1:D")
DestinyArray = Array("C1:C", "G1:G", "T1:T")

lastRow = Sheets(1).Range("C" & Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = LBound(SourceArray) To UBound(SourceArray) Step 1
    Sheets(2).Range(DestinyArray(i) & lastRow).Value = Sheets(1).Range(SourceArray(i) & lastRow).Value
Next i

Erase SourceArray
Erase DestinyArray


End Sub
```

Easy to update if you need to copy more columns, but remember this code will copy always same quantity of cells so if you are copying ranges of different size, then it won't work.